# Django filter answers by questions - group by with returns a list of values

Tags: django, django-models

I have three tables with foreign key section, question and answer:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    questions = models.TextField() 
    section = models.ForeignKey(
        Section, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name = 'section_question')
    objects = QuestionManagers()

class Answer(models.Model):
    answers = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    answer_is = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    questions = models.ForeignKey(
        Question, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name = 'question_answer')
```

I want to do a query that filters the answers to each question, and tried various ways, but couldn't.

```
class QuestionManagers(models.Manager):
    def question_by_section(self, section):
        if section:
            return self.filter(
                section__slug=section.slug,
            ).values()

    def answer_by_question(self, section):
        if section:
            return self.filter(
                section__slug=section.slug,
            ).values(
                'questions'
            ).values(
                'question_answer__answers'
            )
```

with `question_by_section` you can filter the question but now I am missing the answers.

Comment: Why don't you filter on the Answer model, if you are looking for Answers by section?

Comment: Please do *not* use values. Values should only be used in some very specific cases, often if you want to perform a `GROUP BY` on a certain column, but not when you retrieve simple data to render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate).
If you need to group by another value, add it to an earlier values() clause instead.

**[ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg)** (PostgreSQL) returns a list of values, including nulls, concatenated into an array.

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

class QuestionManagers(models.Manager):
    ...

    def answer_by_question(self, section):
        if section:
            return self.filter(
                section__slug=section.slug,
            ).values('questions').annotate(Count('question_answer'), arr=ArrayAgg('question_answer__answers'))
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.
it is pretty close to what I want, but I need you to show me the answers to the questions, not how many answers each question has. Is there an expression that does it?

Comment: @elian18, Do you use postgres?

Comment: if I use Postgres. thanks for taking the time to help me, the arrayagg helped me

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry I'm new and I didn't know what was being voted on, I think I did it there

Answer (score 1):

Cant you define an `AnswerManager`, if you want answers filtered by section?

Maybe like this:

```py
class AnswerManager(models.Manager):
    def answer_by_section(self, section):
        if section:
            return self.filter(questions__section__slug=section.slug)

class Answer(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = AnswerManager()
```

Comment: **thanks for answering me**.
the problem is that a "section" has several questions, and with that query it returns the answers to all the questions